# How to extend constant array in C++ using a base array

Tags: c++, arrays

In C++, is it possible to declare a constant array as an extension of a smaller constant array?

For example, if I have the following array:

```
const uint32 oid_base[] = {1,3,6,1,4,1,72000};
const uint32 oid_complete[] = {1,3,6,1,4,1,72000,1,1};
```

Is there a way to declare `oid_complete` using `oid_base` in the declaration of `oid_complete`?

My guess is that this is not possible in C++, but was wondering if someone had a good solution for this.

Comment: What does snmp have to do with this?

Comment: SNMP defines OIDs in this manner.  Some code uses a MIB file.  However, some code uses sequence definitions that are very repetitive that could be simplified if the sequence could be defined as a constant which depends on a shorter sequence.

Comment: I don't think there is a standard feature for this. But if you use `std::array` instead you could write one. The simple solution is to just use `std::vector`, though it has costs associated with dynamic allocation you may not have to pay here.

Comment: That's fine for motivation. But there is nothing snmp specific about this question, so I've removed the tag.

Comment: Can probably do it with a m*cro.

Comment: That makes sense.  I am trying to do it with an array to interface more cleanly with legacy SNMP code, however, I agree that a `std::vector` would be the easiest solution.

Comment: Based on the comments, it seems that a macro is the best solution for my situation.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: <PANIC> "macro" and "best solution" in the same sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't this what `gsl::span` is for?

```
const uint32_t oid_complete_data[] = {1,3,6,1,4,1,72000,1,1};

const gsl::span<const uint32_t> oid_complete{
  oid_complete_data,
  sizeof(oid_complete_data)};

const gsl::span<const uint32_t> oid_base{
  oid_complete_data,
  sizeof(oid_complete_data)-2};
```

(cf. https://godbolt.org/z/bGeGeP)

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to do it with a for loop, but that requires that the element type is default-constructible. Not sure if you can do element-wise construction a la std::vector in constexpr C++20...

Anyway, you can always use index sequences. Please don't use a macro.
I'm pretty sure there's a duplicate question somewhere by the way, with probably more elegant and general answers.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <cstddef>

template<typename T, std::size_t... Is, typename... Extra>
constexpr auto extend_impl(std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)> const& base,
                           std::index_sequence<Is...>,
                           Extra&&... extra)
{
    return std::array{base[Is]..., std::forward<Extra>(extra)...};
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N, typename... Extra>
constexpr auto extend(std::array<T, N> const& base, Extra&&... extra)
{
    return extend_impl(base, std::make_index_sequence<N>{},
                       std::forward<Extra>(extra)...);
}

constexpr std::array base = {1, 2, 3};
constexpr std::array extended = extend(base, 4, 5, 6);

int main()
{
    for(auto e : extended)
        std::cout << e << " ";
}
```

[On Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/8KTnfW)